# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null / Oracle JET

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

Hello I'm a beginner in JS and Oracle JET Framework.

I'm trying to implement a Panel Expand/Collapse item in my project (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet-310/jetCookbook.html?component=animation&demo=panelExpand) and I have this error I don't know why I followed the cookbook. Here is my code :

## My HTML :

```
<div id="animationDemo">

    <div id="panel" class="oj-panel oj-margin basepanel">
      <h3>Panel Expand/Collapse Demo</h3>
      <div>Primary Content</div>
      <div id="extra-content" class="oj-panel oj-panel-alt2 childpanel">Extra Content</div>
      <button class="oj-panel-resize-button" 
              data-bind="click: buttonClick,
                         ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton', 
                                       chroming: 'half',
                                       display: 'icons', 
                                       icons: buttonIcons, 
                                       label: buttonLabel}"></button>
   </div>

</div>
```

## My JS

define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout', 
'promise', 'ojs/ojtable', 'ojs/ojarraytabledatasource','ojs/ojbutton', 'ojs/ojanimation'],
 function(oj, ko, $) {

```
function CustomerViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  ////

  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
  var extra = document.getElementById('extra-content');  
  var initHeight = $(panel).css('height');

  // Keep track of whether the element is expanded
  self.expanded = false;
  self.buttonIcons = ko.observable({end:'oj-panel-expand-icon'});
  self.buttonLabel = ko.observable('expand');

  self.buttonClick = function() {
    if (self.expanded) {
      // Call the collapse method, then hide the extra content when animation ends.
      oj.AnimationUtils['collapse'](panel, {'endMaxHeight': initHeight}).then(function() {
        extra.style.display = 'none';
        self.expanded = false;
        self.buttonIcons({end:'oj-panel-expand-icon'});
        self.buttonLabel('expand');
      });
    } else {
      // Mark the extra content to be displayed, followed by a call to the expand method.
      extra.style.display = 'block';
      oj.AnimationUtils['expand'](panel, {'startMaxHeight': initHeight}).then(function() {
        self.expanded = true;
        self.buttonIcons({end:'oj-panel-collapse-icon'});
        self.buttonLabel('collapse');
      });
    }
  };
  ///


  self.connected = function() {
    // Implement if needed
  };

  self.disconnected = function() {
    // Implement if needed
  };

  self.transitionCompleted = function() {
  };

  self.hello2 = function() {
    alert('hhhh');
  };
}


return new CustomerViewModel();
 }
);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the HTML hasn't loaded yet when it comes to these lines:

```
var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
var extra = document.getElementById('extra-content');  
var initHeight = $(panel).css('height');
```

So their values become null.

Instead, you could call them only after the document has loaded using jQuery, like this:

```
var panel;
var extra;
var initHeight;

$(document).ready(function(){
    panel = document.getElementById('panel');
    extra = document.getElementById('extra-content');
    initHeight = $(panel).css('height');
});
```

Or if you want to do it the pure OJET way, you could do this:

```
var panel;
var extra;
var initHeight;

self.handleBindingsApplied = function(){ 
    panel = document.getElementById('panel');
    extra = document.getElementById('extra-content');
    initHeight = $(panel).css('height');
};
```

`self.handleBindingsApplied` is an internal method of an OJET Viewmodel that gets called automatically after the binding between the HTML and Viewmodel is complete.

You can read more about all the internal methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet310/jet/developer/GUID-ABB82BD1-9B65-44D2-AE43-81A0A3A44453.htm#JETDG-GUID-ABB82BD1-9B65-44D2-AE43-81A0A3A44453).

P.S. don't forget to apply the CSS as well from the cookbook.